# Calling Watson API from R

Tags: r, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I created my Language Identification service on Bluemix and I am trying to call it using R.

[image]

http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/#!/language-identification/identify

This is the code that I am using:

```
library(httr)
login <- "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/laser/service/api/v1/txtlid/bb0e9e07-cf44-4e95-a5a1-3fb0d53ac98f"
pars <- list(
  sid="lid-generic",
  txt="how are you"
)
POST(login, authenticate("my_username", "my_password@p"), body = pars)
```

The response that I get is of course not the expected, with error 401. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

the result I get from this is:

```
Response [https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/laser/service/api/v1/txtlid/bb0e9e07-cf44-4e95-a5a1-3fb0d53ac98f]
  Date: 2015-01-23 12:29
  Status: 401
  Content-type: text/html
  Size: 252 B
--------------------------4bd32c1a987ed099
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sid"

lid-generic
--------------------------4bd32c1a987ed099
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="txt"

how are you
--------------------------4bd32c1a987ed099--
```

Comment: are you sure that is realy the correct url? Seems to be a session id in the end? Perhaps https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/laser/service/api/v1/txtlid/0 will work better?

Comment: I actually forgot two things

to  add the rt parameter which is used to specify the return.

pars is being sent as form-urlencoded

Answer (score 2):

Here are some "R" code snippets here that might be helpful:
    https://github.com/rustyoldrake/R_Scripts_for_Watson

Briefly - syntax is below showing authentication with "username_password" using getURL (RCurl) and POST (HTTR)

```
### Initialize Creds and URL
base_url = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog-beta/api/v1" 
username = "9XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX" # from Bluemix Service Credentials
password = "123123123123"
username_password = paste(username,":",password,sep="")


###### FUNCTION - CHECK CLASSIFIER STATUS (DIALOG Example)
watson.nlc.checkclassifierstatus <- function(classifier_id) {
  return(
    getURL(paste(base_url,classifier_id,sep=""),userpwd = username_password)
  )
}

###### FUNCTION CREATE NEW CLASSIFIER  (NLC Example)
watson.nlc.createnewclassifier <- function(file,classifiername) {
  return(POST(url="https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers",
         authenticate(username,password),
         body = list(training_data = upload_file(file),
                     training_metadata = paste("{\"language\":\"en\",\"name\":",classifiername,"}",sep="") 
         )))}
```

Answer (score 1):

http 401 indicates authentication issues; presumably you have a userid/password that got assigned to your service instance when you created it.  You will need to pass these in as the userid/password on the HTTP invocation in R.

You seem to be doing that in your code:

```
POST(login, authenticate("my_username", "my_password@p"), body = pars)
```

I wonder if you just copied the wrong userid/password into those values in the `authenticate()` call.